# Why are python unittest tests not found when specifying the module, but are found with path and discovery?

Tags: python

Folder structure:

```
my-package
    my_module
        __init__.py
        ...
    tests
        __init__.py
       test_menu_csv.py
       ...
```

Current working directory: `~/my-package`

I run: `python -m unittest`

```
Ran 30 tests in 20.307s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

I run: `python -m unittest tests/`

```
$ python -m unittest tests/
E
======================================================================
ERROR: tests/ (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests/'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I run: `python -m unittest tests/test_menu_csv.py`

```
......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

I run: `python -m unittest tests`

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why can I not specify the `tests` module only? Discovery picks up on tests in submodules of `my_module` that I don't want to run.

Comment: Sounds to me you're missing some `__init__.py` files in your modules. E.G: `tests/`

Comment: `tests` is not a module in the current search path (which implicitly includes the directory containing a *script*, but not the current working directory).

Comment: What do I need to do to make it a module in the current search path?

Comment: Try `PYTHONPATH=. python -m unittest tests`.

Comment: No luck `Ran 0 tests`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that `python -m unittest tests` "works". It looks like `tests/` is being treated as  literal module name, not a file path, so it's not too surprising it fails. Why  it's not treated as a file path, resulting in a different error, I don't know. I also don't know why `tests` is imported but doesn't find/run any tests.

Comment: (Just for completeness, after having seen that `tests/` and `tests` are treated differently, try `PYTHONPATH=. python -m unittest tests/` (with the trailing `/`).

Comment: Still `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests/'`